# TypeError: Cannot read property 'day' of undefined Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a birthday discord bot. I already coded a command that saves bdays in JSON file. But when I want to read it this error pops up: TypeError: Cannot read property 'day' of undefined.

**If you have any ideas please tell me, thanks :D**

I was following one dude on youtube but he was doing it all in main.js

main.js:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '?';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'jsidement') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'help') {
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'mute') {
        client.commands.get('mute').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'unmute') {
        client.commands.get('unmute').execute(message, args);
    }else if(command === 'setbday'){
        client.commands.get('setbday').execute(message, args);
    }else if(command === 'bday'){
        client.commands.get('bday').execute(message, args);
    }
})

client.login('Token');
```

bday.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    name: 'bday',
    description: 'this is a bday command!',
    execute(message, args){
        client.bdays = require('./bdays.json');

        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        let _bday = client.bdays[target.id].day;
        message.channel.send ('bday is :' +_bday);
    }
}
```

and this is how bdays.json looks like:

```
{
    "453556418352513025": {
        "day": "16",
        "month": "1",
        "year": "2006",
        "id": "BookOfMonsterman04"
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug `let _bday = client.bdays[target.id].day;` line and check what contains each value to know where is the bug.

Comment: How do I Debug a line? I'm new to JavaScript

Comment: The easiest way is doing `console.log()`. For example check `target.id` exists doing `console.log(target.id)` and checking the output. Then you can see which value return undefined and the bug is related with that.

Comment: It look that it's confussed about all of them. If you want I can send here the code that writes data into the JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who need help I ended up changing the whole code. Now it looks like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    name: 'bday',
    description: 'this is a bday command!',
    execute(message, args, Discord){
      
      
      
      const target = message.mentions.users.first();
      fs.readFile("./bdays.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("File read failed:", err);
        }else{
          const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
          let bday = data[target.id].day;
          let bmonth = data[target.id].month;
          let byear = data[target.id].year;
          const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Birthday')
            .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstleyVEVO')
            .addFields(
                {name: 'Day', value: bday},
                {name: 'Month', value: bmonth},
                {name: 'Year', value: byear}
                );  
          message.channel.send(newEmbed);
        }
      });
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the content of `bdays.json` as an array while it is not. replace the external `{}` with square brackets

Comment: Which {}? The in bdays.json? So it will look like: `[
    "453556418352513025": {
        "day": "16",
        "month": "1",
        "year": "2006",
        "id": "BookOfMonsterman04"
    }
]`

Comment: yes. the actual content is not an array so you can use it as an array. that's why i told you to replace